# How can i apply and/or remove a CSS class upon user selection on Radiobuttons with JQuery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, css

My Aspx markup is as follows.
The visitor may select the answer by choosing the "winning question" radiobutton

The HiddenFields contain `True` or `False`

So if the user selects the rdAnsBool1 and the value of the HiddenField1 is "True", 
the JQuery should add a "correct" CSS class to the parent div with ID = Answer

If the user selects the rdAnsBool1 and the value of the HiddenField1 is "False", the JQuery should add a "wrong" CSS class to the parent div with ID = Answer

```
<div id="Answer" class="Ans">
   <div id ="Left"> 
   <asp:RadioButton ID="rdAnsBool1" runat="server" Text = '<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Ans1") %>' />
   <asp:RadioButton ID="rdAnsBool2" runat="server" Text = '<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Ans2") %>' />
   <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server" Value = '<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Ans1Bool") %>'/>
   <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField2" runat="server" Value = '<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Ans2Bool") %>'/>
   </div>
</div>
```

How can this be with JQuery?

**Update.**
The Answer div is located within a Listview. This is the reason i would like to paint the parent div.

**Just another Update**
I am afraid of JQuery...

The markup has changed to the following... for this reason i offer 200 boundy for the winning solution.

```
<div id="Answer" class="Ans">
           <div id ="Left"> 
           <asp:RadioButton ID="rdAnsBool1" runat="server" Text = '<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Ans1") %>' />
           <asp:RadioButton ID="rdAnsBool2" runat="server" Text = '<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Ans2") %>' />
           <asp:RadioButton ID="rdAnsBool3" runat="server" Text = '<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Ans3") %>' />
           <asp:RadioButton ID="rdAnsBool4" runat="server" Text = '<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Ans4") %>' />
           <asp:RadioButton ID="rdAnsBool5" runat="server" Text = '<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Ans5") %>' />
           <asp:RadioButton ID="rdAnsBool6" runat="server" Text = '<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Ans6") %>' />
           <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server" Value = '<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Ans1Bool") %>'/>
           <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField2" runat="server" Value = '<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Ans2Bool") %>'/>
           <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField3" runat="server" Value = '<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Ans3Bool") %>'/>
           <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField4" runat="server" Value = '<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Ans4Bool") %>'/>
           <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField5" runat="server" Value = '<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Ans5Bool") %>'/>
           <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField6" runat="server" Value = '<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Ans6Bool") %>'/>
           </div>
        </div>
```

And here is the JsFiddle part

http://jsfiddle.net/VTevz/

This thing is driving me nuts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// get a reference to radio button and attach change handler
$('input[id*="rdAnsBool"]').change(function(){
     var container = $(this).closest('div.Ans'),
         questionid = $(this).attr('id'),
         index = questionid[questionid.indexOf('rdAnsBool') + 1];

     // test for condition and set classes accordingly ...
     if($(this).val() == $(this).parent()
                                .find('input[id*="HiddenField' + index + '"]').val()) {
          container.addClass('correct').removeClass('wrong');
          return;
     }

     container.addClass('wrong').removeClass('correct');
});
```

**Update** *(Make sure you post the HTML markup and not ASP markup when working in the browser context)*:

http://jsfiddle.net/VTevz/7/

Comment: Hello, thank you for your support. But this kind of solution does not apply in Parent div's but in every "Answer" div, right? Or am i missing something here?

Comment: @Chocol8 this is assuming you only have ***one answer div*** as `id`s are unique ...

Comment: @Chocol8 I just updated my answer for ***multiple answer divs*** using the `CSS class name`

Comment: I guess i have to make a new question since i found that there may be more than three radio buttons for each question...

Comment: I just updated my answer to hopefully solve your issue. It would help if you posted a snippet of the `HTML source` and not the `ASP Markup`

Comment: @Chocol8 there was a syntax error, I corrected it. Nonetheless, you should have gotten the idea by now...

Comment: Hello sir, unfortunatelly it does not work too. After some debugging i found that you should add the length of the rdAnsBool to get the right index... index = questionid[questionid.indexOf('rdAnsBool') + 1 + 8]; The second part is that the $(this).parent().find('input[id*="HiddenField' + index + '"]').val() always returns Undefined. You can find the Html here  http://jsfiddle.net/VTevz/ Please keep in mind that the block you see is repeated since it is within a listview control. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the hidden has the same name as the `radiobutton` and there you go:

```
$('input[type=radio]').change(function() {
    if (this.checked == $('input[type=hidden],[name=' + this.name + ']').val()) {
        $(this).closet('#Answer').removeClass('correct').addClass('wrong');
    }
    else {
        $(this).closet('#Answer').removeClass('wrong').addClass('correct');
    }
});
```

Comment: Could you help me a bit more by saying Make sure the hidden has the same name as the radiobutton? I do not understand your approach

Comment: @Chocol8. Give me a JSFiddle with the HTML, I will adjust it.

Comment: @Chocol8. I can't understand the language(or even recognize it) And it has broken images links, and it's way too long, give me the shortest version that you can. sorry...

Comment: @Chocol8. It's still has that foreign language. and it's more than 300 lines, and it's still has broken links. I need the simplest HTML, and in **English**

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#rdAnsBool1').click(function(e) {
    if ($('#HiddenField1').attr('Value')=='True') {
        $('#Answer').addClass('correct');
    } else {
        $('#Answer').addClass('wrong');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have not grouped the radio buttons they both can be selected at the same time. You should specify the `GroupName` in both the buttons with same name.

After you specify the name, lets say "answers" you can try this.

```
$('input[name="answers"]').click(function(){
    if($('#HiddenField' + $(this).index()).val().toLowerCase() == "true"){
        $("#Answer").removeClass('wrong').addClass('correct');  
    }
    else{
        $("#Answer").removeClass('correct').addClass('wrong');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be easier if you added a value of the hidden field's ClientID to your respective radio buttons. You can do this in your code-behind (e.g., in the radio button's pre-render event: `RadioButton1.Attributes.Add("value", HiddenField1.ClientID)`). You should also probably add a CSSClass to the buttons you have marked for choices (i.e., `CSSClass="choice"` or `RadioButton1.Attributes.Add("class", "choice")` depending on if you want to do it in markup or code-behind).

That should change your rendered markup to `<input type="radio" value="ctl00_cphMain_HiddenField1" name="ctl00$cphMain$RadioButton1" id="ctl00_cphMain_RadioButton1">` (or something substantially similar).

Once your markup is modified, your jQuery becomes:

```
$('input.choice[type="radio"]').click(function () {
    var $this = $(this);         //easy alias.
    var answer = $this.val();   //hidden field id
    var cssClass = '';
    if ($this.attr('checked')) {
        cssClass = $(answer).val().toLowerCase() === 'true' ? 'correct' : 'wrong';
    }
    $this.removeClass('correct').removeClass('wrong').addClass(cssClass).;
});
```